# How can I pass the selected value from p-dropdown to ts?

Tags: javascript, angular, p-dropdown

This is an example of code for p-dropdown.

```js
// product.component.html
<p-dropdown
    [options]="products"
    optionLabel="productName"
    placeholder="Select a product"
>
</p-dropdown>
```

This is json data I am getting from API. In the `p-dropdown`, the `productName` is successfully shown.

```json
// products data
[
    {
        productName: "Apple",
        productId: 1
    },
    {
        productName: "Banana",
        productId: 2
    },
    {
        productName: "Peach",
        productId: 3
    },
]
```

My question is, when users select the product, how to store `productId` from the selected product to a newly created variable in ts? There are multiple `p-dropdown` in `p-table`'s rows so I want to store the multiple `productId` selected values into an array `selectedProductId`.

```js
// product.component.ts
// How to store productID from the selected product to a newly created variable in ts?
selectedProductId!: any[];
```

Comment: Please don't use `any`; have you seen [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) in the handbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read the documentation at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13/dropdown

In your case it seems be possible do that:

in your.component.html:

```
<p-dropdown
    (onChange)="selectProduct($event?.value)"
    [options]="products"
    optionLabel="productName"
    optionValue="productId">
</p-dropdown>
```

in your.component.ts:

```
selectedProductId: number[] = [];

selectProduct(id: number) {
    if (!this.selectedProductId.includes(id))
        this.selectedProductId.push(id);
}
```